# How to query a Firestore database from a web app outside of the same firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### Problem

I am building a website for a mobile app, App A. I am using firebase to host my website. The website is associated with the same firebase project as App A. Another mobile app I already developed, App B, has a firestore database that I want to be used as a 'news' datasource for App A's website. App B's database is in a different firebase project than the website of App A. I am unable to bridge the connection between app A's website and App B's database.

### AC

Using firebase, successfully query data from App B's database from the website of App A.

Use firebase environment configuration variables to store private credentials of App B's database.

### Setup

Developer mode enabled inside the database of App B (Allow everything).

#### Web App A start file...

```
    functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
    downloadNews = require("./db/news/downloadLatestNews");
    transporter = require("./middleware/transport");
    const appA = firebase.initializeApp();
    appADatabase = appA.firestore();
    appADatabase.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});

    const appB = firebase.initializeApp({
        credential: firebase.credential.cert({
               projectId: functions.config().appB.project_id,
               clientEmail: functions.config().appB.client_email,
                privateKey: functions.config().appB.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
          }),
          databaseURL: functions.config().appB.database_url
       }, "AppB");
   appBDatabase = firebase.firestore(appB);
   appBDatabase.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});
```

#### Module inside Web App A to query from App B's database...

This function is invoked each time a user makes a request to the '/news' route of Web App A.

```
const Post = require("../../models/post");

exports.downloadRecent = function() {
  var ref = appBDatabase.collection("users").doc(functions.config().appB.user_id).collection("post_storage");
  ref = ref.where('is_public', '==', true);
  ref = ref.limit(16);
  console.log(ref);

  return ref.get().then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        console.log("No documents exist for userID: " + functions.config().appB.user_id);
        // Gonna pass back a generic check again soon
        return null;
    }

    const docs = snapshot.docs;
    // Empty array of post prms to return
    console.log("The snapshot returned: " + docs);
    var all_prms = [];
    // Create each doc as a post
    docs.forEach(doc => {
        var post = new Post(doc.data());
        console.info("Post data: " + doc.data());
        all_prms.push(post);
    });
    return Promise.all(all_prms);
 })
 .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error getting posts: " + err);
    return;
 });
};
```

### Results

Every attempt to query data from App B's database returns no documents. I can verify documents exist and meet the criteria for the query.

Any advise on things that I may be doing wrong would be really appreciated. I should conclude by stating that I am not a web developer and have little experience.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?